# Distinguishing between orthonormal vectors generated by Gram-Schmidt procedure using different set of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

We all know Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization is highly non-democratic, i.e. performing the Gram-Schmidt procedure on the linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3, \cdots , v_n$ will result in a different set of orthonormal vectors then performing it on $v_{i_1}, v_{i_2}, v_{i_3}, \cdots , v_{i_n}$ , where $i_1, i_2, \cdots , i_n$ is a permutation of $1,2 \cdots n$.

I want to know is it possible to distinguish the two orthonormal sets of vectors generated by the Gram-Schmidt procedure using different set of vectors.
I.e., Is it possible to distinguish between the orthonormal vectors generated by
$$v_1, v_2, v_3, \cdots , v_n \quad \text{and} \quad v_{i_1}, v_{i_2}, v_{i_3}, \cdots , v_{i_n}$$
from the orthonormal vectors generated using the set
$$v_1, v_2, \cdots v_{n-k}, w_1, \cdots w_k$$

If you can provide me any method to distinguish between them it would be great. But I am mostly interested in knowing that even theoretically is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Let start by looking at a linear space of dimension equal to one. I.e. isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ if we're speaking of linear spaces over the field $\mathbb R$.

$\{1\}$ is a linearly independent set of vector(s). As is $\{2\}$.

For both cases, the Gram–Schmidt process leads to $\{1\}$ as the obtained orthonormal basis. And you have no way to know what was the original basis.

To make it short: **the Gram–Schmidt process is not one-to-one.**

Comment: okay, so two different sets of vectors give the same orthonormal set under Gram-Schmidt. Do you know if there is such a non-democratic orthogonalization procedure for which this distinction is actually possible?

Comment: This is not possible. You only have two orthonormal bases for $\mathbb R$. Namely $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$. While you have a continuum $\mathfrak u$ number of independent vectors. Namely all the $\{u\}$ where $0 \neq u \in \mathb R$. As the cardinal of the continuum is bigger than $2$, you'll never be able to find a one-to-one process. *Note: not sure that using the term democratic makes sense here!*.